# How can I zoomToExtent and then zoom out?

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, html5

I use openlayers 2.12

I use HTML5's geolocation API to get the coords and then I insert them in a layer as feature (point). After that, I zoom in , since the layer has no other feature.

```
map.zoomToExtent(geoloc.getDataExtent());
```

`geoloc` is the name of the layer...

My problem is, how do I zoom-out automatically after the `zoomToExtent`?

Because the map zooms in too much and I can see just the point and very little details. It would be more user-friendly to zoom out a bit

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to zoom out one zoomlevel? Or to a particular ZoomLevel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to ZoomTo a specific ZoomLevel , you can use `Map.zoomTo` like this:

```
map.zoomTo(level); \\where level is an integer, indicating the zoom level
```

If you just want to Zoom out one level, you can use `Map.zoomOut` like this:

```
map.zoomOut()
```

Answer (score 1):

`map.setCenter` is useful, as it moves the map to the location as well as to a specified zoom level.

My code

```
function geolocate() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(position.coords.longitude,
                position.coords.latitude)
            .transform(
                new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), //transform from WGS 1984
                map.getProjectionObject() //to Spherical Mercator Projection
            );
        markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat)); //markers is a marker layer
        map.setCenter(lonLat, zoom); //lotlat is geolocation and zoom is the zoom level you want
        alert("your position is located");
    });
}
```